# Почему input type="file" работает по-разному в браузерах

Tags: html

столкнулась вот с какой проблемой:

когда кликаешь на инпут, открывается окно выбора файла...файл выбрал...нажимаешь снова на инпут и отменяешь ("отменить"/крестик) и понеслось) в хроме и опере сбрасывается выбранный файл (вертаемся к изначальному инпуту "файл не выбран"), а в FF и IE сброса не происходит.

и не могу разобраться, в чем причина...есть какие-нибудь варианты?

Спасибо)

Comment: варианты вы вроде уже описали. очевидно, зависит от реализации конкретного браузера. Разве это проблема в целом?

Comment: просто хочется понять))))думала проблема с моей стороны...я что-то не так делаю

Comment: Для того что б работало одинаково или более менее одинаково - используют *кроссбраузерные* решения.